# How to delete a value if it already exists in a Javascript Set

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, set

I have a table where a user can select a row, when they do so, the PK of the row entry is saved to a set, however, if they select it again, i want to delete that value from the set. Does anybody know how this should be done?

**JS & JQ**

```js
let bill = new Set()

$("body").on('click', '#food_table tbody tr', function() {
  var key = $(this).find(".key").text();
  var keyInt = parseInt(key)
  console.log(keyInt)

  bill.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item === keyInt) {
      bill.delete(item);
    } else {
      bill.add(keyInt)
    }
  });

  console.log(bill)
});
```

When i run it, i don't get any errors, but the 'bill' set just stays empty.

**html if necessary**

```
<table class="table table table-borderless" id="food_table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {% for objects in object %}
        <tr>
          <td class="key">{{ objects.food_item.pk }}</td>
          <td>{{ objects.food_item.food }} </td>
          <td>{{ objects.food_item.price }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Please think again about what the `if (...) { ... delete ... } else { ... add ... }` part does in a `forEach`. More specifically, how often do you expect `add` and `remove` to be called, and do you expect only one of each, if the set has more than one element? What if it is empty, like at the start?

Comment: If your element is not in the `Set` you add it at the end of the `Set` in the first iteration  which gets deleted in the last iteration, If your element exists in your `Set` it gets deleted in `nth` iteration then gets added back in `n+1th` iteration and then again gets deleted in the last iteration . So your `bill Set` stays at it was at the end of iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the `Set`. If the set [`has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) the value, delete it. Else, `add` the value to the set.

```js
if (bill.has(keyInt))
  bill.delete(keyInt)
else
  bill.add(keyInt)
```